# copy a site collection by backup & restore it to a new URL

Tags: 2013, development, administration, backup, restore

I am currently working on a site collection of type team site , and I did many customization and I create many sub sites inside it. Now our customer requested to have another site collection with the same settings to be used for different purpose. So I found that I can copy the current site collection and do some renaming mainly for the CT & site columns and I can achieve this .. But not sure if my current approach is supported or not:-

- I am planning to back-up the current site collection (SCA).
- Create a new site collection of type team site (SCB).
- Restore the backup site collection on the new URL.
- In this way I will have a copy of SCA inside SCB . Now to reset the entire item IDs and other version history for my lists & list items inside SCB. I will do the following.

  - For all the sub sites that have been copied inside SCB , i will save them as site templates (without the content).
  - Then I will remove the actual sub sites from SCB, and create new subsites based of the site templates.
  - In this case I will have the same copy of SCA inside SCB and also without having any content (I will have a brand new site collection).

So can anyone advice on the above approach.. Now I did a test and seems it will workcwell, but I am afraid of any behind the senses problems ?

Thanks.